# Books on Introductory Statistical Mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations

Can anyone recommend a good book on Basic Statistical Mechanics? I have an engineering background and had to go through loads of different books to learn General Relativity. I found Peter Collier's A Most Incomprehensible Thing to be a fine book after Hartle's book on Gravity. So, is there any text which treats Statistical Mechanics in a simple, elementary enough way?

Comment: [Reif's Statistical Physics](http://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Physics-Berkeley-Course-Vol/dp/0070048622) is the one I would pick for you.

Comment: Take a look at Statistical physics of particles by Mehran Kardar. If that seems too formal to you, then I suggest that you pick up Statistical Mechanics by D.A.Mcquarrie, as it might be more comprehensible...

Answer (score 2):

== EDIT ==

I'd like to suggest Statistical Mechanics In a Nutshell - Luca Peliti. It presents deep knowledge in a very simple way. I like it mathematically also.

== END EDIT ==

In a introductory level, I think the best shot is **Daniel V. Schroeder: An Introduction to Thermal Physics**. It exposes thermodynamics in a modern point of view, connecting that to statistical mechanics. In other hand, the statistical mechanics is basic but solid in concepts. The best book I got in my undergraduation course. This book is easily find at libgen and there's a website with its content to read each section by time: https://physicspages.com/schroeder%20thermal.html.

There are a brazilian book considered so good, but I think it misses some important steps of physical and mathematical thoughts: **Introdução à Física Estatística - S. Salinas**. (Introduction to Statistical Physics - translated to english)

I've just found this one: **Kurth R - Axiomatics of classical statistical mechanics (1960, Pergamon)**. I got your question while searching for references in Statiscal mechanics with mathematical perspective. This seems perfect to me, if you like math I suggest you this, after a first reading on Schroeder's book.

The more referenced authors in Statistical Mechanics are:
Silvio Salinas (brazilian - undergraduate & graduate), Reif (undergraduate), Pathria (undergraduate & graduate), Greiner (graduate text)

The levels are exposed as usual.